# Upgrading 8.10 server to LTS

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 8.10, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating Ubuntu server from 8.10 to 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22265/updating-ubuntu-server-from-8-10-to-10-04)

I'm in a plan to upgrade ubuntu 8.10 vbox vm servers to LTS(obviously 10.04) as 8.10 has no support. As far as I know I'll be executing the following to upgrade:

```
apt-get install update-manager-core
do-release-upgrade
```

anybody could tell me how could I upgrade a ubuntu server from alternate iso image(Is the alternate iso image used for desktop editons the same used for servers?)?

I heard it's possible to upgrade an LTS directly to another LTS and how could I do this after upgrading 8.10 to 9.04 then directly to 10.04 skipping 9.10?

8.10 servers are hosting many services/applications/databases like apache2, tomcat6, ldap, mysql, cvs... and I'm not sure that all of them work as ever after the upgrade.
If there is any precautions that I've to following before upgrading, please anyone let me know(ofcourse backup and I'm not going to take backup as I will be trying this on a copy of vdi/vmdk vms)

Thanks!

Comment: Following the link I couldn't upgrade!

Comment: Alteast there would have been a way for upgrading after EOL.

Comment: No way other than installing freshly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTS to LTS upgrades are supported, so you could go from 8.04 to 10.04 directly. However, since you're on 8.10, you would need to upgrade to 9.04, then 9.10, then to 10.04. The primary problem, however, is that 8.10 is extremely out of date. 9.04 is already end-of-life, and 9.10 will be end-of-life in April. This means it will not be easy to upgrade normally.

This was asked here, too:
[Updating Ubuntu server from 8.10 to 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22265/updating-ubuntu-server-from-8-10-to-10-04)

Comment: Oh... so it's not sure that I could upgrade. I'm out of idea what to do!

Comment: Of course not solved as it's not possible, just wanted to close this post