# How to upgrade a remote server from 8.10 to newer version?

Tags: server, upgrade

I have a remote server still running Ubuntu <del>8.10</del> 9.04 that I can only access via SSH.

If I run `apt-get update` I get a bunch of 404 errors on the packages. I've asked a few questions on Server Fault but got nowhere. Here's what I've done:

1. Run `apt-get update` which returns errors like:

   > Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/main Packages
   >   404 Not Found
   >   [and same for many other packages]
2. Run `do-release-upgrade` which returns:

   > Checking for a new ubuntu release
   >   Failed Upgrade tool signature
   >   Failed Upgrade tool
   >   Done downloading
   >   extracting 'jaunty.tar.gz'
   >   Failed to extract
   >   Extracting the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
3. Edited `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and changed from `Prompt=normal` to `Prompt=lts` (as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/236001/upgrading-ubuntu-server)). Running  `do-release-upgrade` after this returns:

   > Checking for a new ubuntu release
   >   current dist not found in meta-release file
   >   No new release found
4. (Updated) I have followed the advice in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22265/updating-ubuntu-server-from-8-10-to-10-04) and changed `/etc/apt/sources.list` to refer to `jaunty` instead of `intrepid`. However, that distro is not online anymore either. A comment there says I have to upgrade in chronological order...

So basically, it seems like I cannot upgrade because my current distro is out of date and not supported. Is there a way to upgrade direct to 10.x or 11.x? Note, as this is a server *I only have command-line access*.

**UPDATE 24/11:** I have managed to upgrade from 8.10 to 9.04. Ubuntu's [EOL Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Intrepid) page provides some alternate URLs for apt sources. I also needed to update `/var/lib/update-manager/meta-release` to point to the old-releases server too.

However, now I cannot upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10. Running `do-release-upgrade` produces the same error as #2 above, except it "Failed to fetch" (the URLs in `meta-release` are valid). The Ubuntu Jaunty upgrade page says it's necessary to upgrade using a CD image. I followed the [instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#Upgrades_via_alternate_CD), but it didn't work:

> A fatal error occurred
>
> Please report this as a bug and include the files 
>   /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log in 
>   your report. The upgrade is now aborted.  Your original sources.list
>   was saved in  /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/karmic", line 7, in  
>   sys.exit(main())
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 132, in main  if
>   app.run():
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1590, in 
>   run  return self.fullUpgrade()
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1506, in 
>   fullUpgrade  if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/DistUpgradeController.py", line 762, in 
>   doPostInitialUpdate  self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 83, in run  for
>   plugin in self.plugin_manager.get_plugins(condition):
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/computerjanitor/plugin.py", line 167, in 
>   get_plugins  filenames = self.get_plugin_files()
>
> File "/tmp/tmp.JLhTwVUugb/computerjanitor/plugin.py", line 120, in 
>   get_plugin_files  basenames = [x for x in os.listdir(dirname)
>
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './plugins'

It does say to report the bug, but since this is an old unsupported release I don't know if it's worth doing. **However, is there a way round this, to upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10** (And then finally to 10.04 LTS.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Ubuntu server from 8.10 to 10.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22265/updating-ubuntu-server-from-8-10-to-10-04)

Comment: @qbi that question doesn't solve the problem because the jaunty repos are no longer available. A comment on that page suggests I must install upgrades in order...

Comment: if the server is on a closed network, leave well alone.  Its doing a good job :)  If you want to use the LTS - back stuff up and go for a clean install.  Under no circumstances should you attempt to skip upgrade versions - it will only give you severe headaches.

Comment: @fossfreedom the problem is, I'm having a few problems with some software (webmin) that relies on a few things I am unable to install.

Comment: ok ... then a fresh install is still my recommendation. For servers I would stick with the LTS releases since you have 5 years support rather than 18months... If you can explain in your question what software you have on the server, maybe someone can point you in the right direction how to migrate data from one software version to the LTS version.

Comment: in the last link you used do-release-upgrade - however the recommendation for the server was to download the alternate CD and do a `sudo ./cdromupgrade --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText` - you have downloaded the alternate?  does the recommended server upgrade method make a difference?

Comment: @foss I mean I ran `do-release-upgrade` first, but when that didn't work I then followed the linked instructions and did indeed run the command you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update from 'Ubuntu Server 9.04' (Jaunty) to 'Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS' (Lucid).**

based on:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades

http://echenh.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-server-904-to-910.html

**Step 1:** install **update-manager-core**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

**Step 2:** Update from **9.04** (Jaunty) to **9.10** (Karmic)

edit /etc/apt/sources.list to replace "jaunty" with "karmic"

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

**Step 3:** Update **9.10** (Karmic) to **10.04 LTS** (Lucid)

edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts

file should (at minimum) contain:

```
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=lts
```

edit /etc/apt/sources.list to replace "karmic" with "lucid"

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

To check your server version: (at each stage)

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much working spot-on! The only extra thing is when going from *karmic* to *lucid*, I needed to change `sources.list` back to using `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` instead of `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Download a CD, and do an upgrade install. Definitely do a backup first though!

I would recommend updating to 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) though:

1. It's a closer upgrade and less likely to explode.
2. It's an LTS release, and servers that don't get updated often should be running LTS.

The next LTS will be 12.04, but 10.04 will still receive updates for a year after that.

(Edited to correct version number - silly thinko - thanks mikewhatever)

Comment: Lucid Lynx is 10.04. :~)

Comment: This is a Ubuntu server, with command line only access, so a CD is not an option!

Comment: Can you connect a **CD drive**, via USB?  Or insert USB stick, with **10.04.3 LTS**?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, I expect it would be the same as the install instructions for the current release on ubuntu.com. Whether you can boot from USB at all depends on your BIOS/firmware/whatever on your specific machine.

Comment: @david6 no, I do not have access to the machine, only via SSH. I thought I made this clear, sorry. Also as noted in the update, I tried to run the CD install by mounting the ISO image but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, upgrading a *remote* server? That does complicate things ... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was ble with a small tweak to upgrade "as-usual" my Jaunty (9.04) server and Desktop installations to the latest LTS.

I have put all the details [how to do a smooth upgrade from Jaunty to Karmic (even if EOL) in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/135028/3004).