# How To Update Ubuntu 8.10 to Have Recent Updates

Tags: versions, 8.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing packages to end-of-lifed Ubuntu editions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82291/installing-packages-to-end-of-lifed-ubuntu-editions)

When the update manager tries to update the computer, it gives the message :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/transmission/transmission-common_1.34-0ubuntu2.3_all.deb
  404 Not Found
```

Please explain how to update version 8.10 if it gives this message.

Comment: Please backup and reinstall a newer version. It is far better, more efficient and less prone to problems than upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu `8.10` and even `8.04` are no longer [officially supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_timeline).

"After each version of Ubuntu has reached its end-of-life time, its repositories are removed from the main Ubuntu servers and consequently the mirrors."

This might be why you are not able to update transmission. Are you able to upgrade? i.e Does your update manager show the new version available button?

If not you might want to reinstall `12.04` if you want Long term support, else just go for the latest `12.10` version

Alternatively some other methods to do the upgrade are posted at [Updating Ubuntu server from 8.10 to 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22265/updating-ubuntu-server-from-8-10-to-10-04)